# How can I get the memory usage of a worker created by worker_threads in nodejs

Tags: node.js, node-worker-threads

I created a worker using the worker_threads. Like this:

```
const WorkerThreads = require('worker_threads');
const worker = new WorkerThreads.Worker('./path/to/a.js');

if (countMemory(worker) > 100 * 1024 * 1024) {
    worker.terminate();
}

function countMemory(worker) {
    // some code I don't know
}
```

And I knew that the `./path/to/a.js` has a little bit memory leak, so I have to destory the Worker when it  leak a lot. How can I get how many memory did the Worker use?

Answer (score 1):

See the `resourceLimits` option you can pass to the Worker constructor. Should be more useful than manually checking for memory usage in your use case.

https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html#worker_threads_new_worker_filename_options

> resource limits  An optional set of resource limits for the
> new JS engine instance. Reaching these limits will lead to termination
> of the Worker instance. These limits only affect the JS engine, and no
> external data, including no ArrayBuffers. Even if these limits are
> set, the process may still abort if it encounters a global
> out-of-memory situation.

- maxOldGenerationSizeMb  The maximum size of the main heap in MB.
- maxYoungGenerationSizeMb  The maximum size of a heap space for recently created objects.
- codeRangeSizeMb  The size of a pre-allocated memory range used for generated code.
- stackSizeMb  The default maximum stack size for the thread. Small values may lead to unusable Worker instances. Default: 4.

Worker  also has [getHeapSnapshot()](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html#worker_threads_worker_getheapsnapshot) method exposed. As Worker has its own v8 instance running so you can use all [v8](https://nodejs.org/api/v8.html) API to get more details.

Comment: Is the getHeapSnapshot() slow? Its result looks very big. I'm worry about it makes my application pause.

Comment: For your case, `resourceLimits`  is a better choice.  As per docs `getHeapSnapshot()` Generates a snapshot of the current V8 heap and returns a Readable Stream that may be used to read the JSON serialized representation. This JSON stream format is intended to be used with tools such as Chrome DevTools. I believe with snapshot you can identify memory usage pattern int worst-case scenario and then go for `resourceLimits`.

Comment: But as you already have a max memory  limit  configured you can go for the resource limit option

Answer (score 0):

You can use [process.memoryUsage](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_memoryusage) to get the info from all the threads. Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31168351/node-cluster-workers-memoryusage). I think you can use the same approach for worker_threads

Comment: I want to count memory usage of one Worker Thread. The process.memoryUsage() looks count all of threads.